Chrome Extension for Auto log in. Acts like the Username is blank unless I have clicked anywhere on the page
I have a web page in Chrome that I want to have the Extension log into.
When the contentScript runs, it finds the button and clicks it but the page just adds some error text (Input is required) acting like no Username has been entered. The Username is there and added automatically by Chrome. If I click anywhere on the web page before the script runs, the button click is successful.
`      const submit = document.querySelector('.submit-button[tabindex="0"]');
      if (submit) {
        console.log("if (submit)");
        // Click submit button only if found
        if (submit) {
          submit.click();
          console.log("Clicked 'Submit' button!");
        } else {
          console.log("Couldn't find 'Submit' button!");
        }
      }`

I have tried using .focus() on the page, the entry field and the button before trying to click the button and nothing works so far.
I also tried adding a delay to the button click after the page has been open but I don't think it's a timing issue as it always works if I click anywhere on the web page before the script runs.
I also tried tabbing from the Username field.
const submitButton = document.querySelector('.submit-button[tabindex="0"]');
const usernameField = document.querySelector('#username-field');

usernameField.focus(); // Focus on the username field
const tabEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Tab' });
usernameField.dispatchEvent(tabEvent);
submitButton.click();

I also tried document.body.click() but nothing is giving the page the same type of focus as simply clicking on it with the mouse cursor.
